# fa-arrow-circle-o-down & fa-arrow-circle-down

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

I want to use `fa-arrow-circle-down` icon like `fa-arrow-circle-o-down` but it's not possible becaouse these two icons do not have same arrow type. Can we create `fa-arrow-circle-o-down` width `fa-arrow-circle-down`'s arrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that isn't possible with the icons available in Font Awesome 4.0. There is a [`fa-long-arrow-down`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/long-arrow-down/) which is very similar to what you're looking for though.

```
<span class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></span>
```

[image: Example]

If you want this specific icon to be added to Font Awesome, your can make an Icon Request issue on their GitHub repository: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues